# OpenSSL commands in Java?

Tags: java, encryption, openssl, public-key, pkcs#8

So I made a program based off this tut:
http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~ml355/lore/pkencryption.htm

It works perfectly fine, but as you can see at the bottom of the page it requires OpenSSL commands. I used OpenSSL and generated my keys in the correct format to test my program, works perfectly. But I was wondering how I would generate those keys just in Java. I have tried countless times but encryption is so hard to understand for me and to work with. So I have no code to show at the moment, how would I start this or if anyone has a good method for doing so. I don't mind using bouncy castle if it is possible.

TL;DR: I would like to generate a unique Private and Public key in the correct format (PKCS#8, DER) using java (with or without a public library).

Just need these commands in java (not running through OpenSSL):

To generate a private key of length 2048 bits:

```
openssl genrsa -out private.pem 2048
```

To get it into the required (PKCS#8, DER) format:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -in private.pem -outform DER -out private.der -nocrypt
```

To generate a public key from the private key:

```
openssl rsa -in private.pem -pubout -outform DER -out public.der
```

Comment: Start with [the tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/step2.html). It really helps to understand at least loosely how asymmetric key generation works to write code - it makes much more sense that way. Knowing some OpenSSL commands isn't going to help you.

Comment: Honestly - unless you have a lot of time to basically reverse-engineer the openssl tools themselves - you will find this seemingly simple task very complicated and frustrating, speaking from firsthand experience. Openssl is a miserably a documented library to deal with.

Comment: Yes but I was wondering if I could just generate them in the correct format using bouncy castle or some other means..

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network. Perhaps superuser.com to help with converting commands among programs.

Comment: For some of the commands in Java, you would use `keytool`. I'm not sure about some of the other commands when going from OpenSSL to Java, though. The folks on superuser.com can probably help.

Comment: This is not a superuser q - this is very clearly a programming question about coding in Java.

Comment: @Joe - there's no Java code in that question. The question is clearly about the the Java equivalent of OpenSSL commands (check the title). I believe some of the commands have equivalents with Java's `keytool`. I don't know what some of the commands translate into with Java tools. That's why its a superuser.com question.

Answer (score 1):

Generating an RSA keypair is easy in Java. For example:

```
import java.security.*;
import java.security.interfaces.*;

public class RSACreate {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        kpg.initialize(2048, new SecureRandom());
        KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
        RSAPrivateCrtKey rsaPriv = (RSAPrivateCrtKey) kp.getPrivate();
        RSAPublicKey rsaPub = (RSAPublicKey) kp.getPublic();
    }

}
```